# Fail to download HP plugins

Tags: hp, plugins

I am struggling to have my HP Envy 6030 scanning.
I downloaded and installed HPLIP.
I tried both 3.23.6 and 3.22.6 but, in both cases, when I select the scanning option, the system keeps telling me to download plugins from the terminal.
Further doing it, I receive the following message:

error: Found No Section in /tmp/tmpiMoZX8. Please set the http proxy for root and try again. () error: file does not match its checksum. File may have been corrupted or altered

Any help at all ?

Cheers

P.S.

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.6